# Are there 21 different CPU costs for your transaction because of subjective billing?

Tags: cpu

And does it also mean it's cheaper in CPU time when you wait until the BP with the fastest CPU is scheduled for the next 12 blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you can wait for the fastest BP, and also, you can vote out the BP which has slow CPU.